# XSL get value matching a element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML fragment:

```
<process>
  <UserAttr>
    <Name>User1</Name>
    <Value>username1</Value>  
    <Name>User2</Name>
    <Value>username2</Value>
    <Name>User3</Name>
    <Value>username3</Value>
    <Name>User4</Name>
    <Value>username4</Value>
  </UserAttr>
</process>
```

The above XML is dynamic and it can have more/less number of Name & Value tags. I would like to have a assign or transform that will allow me to get a respective value matching the Name.

For eg, if I pass `User1` as a parameter to a XSL transform, it should return the respective  `Value`, i.e `Username1`.

I didn't post my XSL because whatever I posted as XML is just a part of my whole XSD and my XSL is very big and I thought it will be very confusing.

Below is how my XSD looks (this is just that part from a big XSD):

```
<xs:element name="UserAttr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to do the below but it throws SelectionFailure Fault. I think i need to assign array size somewhere in the XSD

```
<assign name="Assign1">
<copy>
<from expression="string('User1')"/>
<to variable="receiveInput_process_InputVariable_3"
part="payload" query="/client:process/UserAttr[position()=1]/@Name"/>
</copy>
<copy>
<from expression="string('User2')"/>
<to variable="receiveInput_process_InputVariable_3"
part="payload" query="/client:process/UserAttr[position()=2]/@Name"/>
</copy>
</assign>
```

Comment: Before asking us to write XSLT for you (1) please show what you've tried, and (2) note that your XML and XSD conflict, possibly in multiple ways: For example, in the XML, `Name` is an **element**; in the XSD, it is an **attribute**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the key name is stored in a parameter named `keyName`, you can get the corresponding value using this XPath:

```
/header/UserAttr/Name[. = $keyName]/following-sibling::*[1][self::Value]
```

This involves an extra precaution to only select a value element that is immediately after the `Name` element, in case you somehow had a malformed list like this:

```
<header>
  <UserAttr>
    <Name>User1</Name>
    <Value>username1</Value>  
    <Name>User2</Name>
    <Name>User3</Name>
    <Name>User4</Name>
    <Value>username4</Value>
  </UserAttr>
</header>
```

So the above would prevent selecting the value `username4` if the key name were `User 2`. If you don't need that extra precaution, you can use this:

```
/header/UserAttr/Name[. = $keyName]/following-sibling::Value[1]
```

In my opinion, though, if you have the ability to change the XML structure, either of the following would make the task simpler and cleaner.

```
<header>
  <UserAttr>
    <Attr>
      <Name>User1</Name>
      <Value>username1</Value>  
    </Attr>
    <Attr>
      <Name>User2</Name>
      <Value>username2</Value>
    </Attr>
    <Attr>  
      <Name>User3</Name>
      <Value>username3</Value>
    </Attr>
  </UserAttr>
</header>
```

```
<header>
  <UserAttr>
    <Attr name="User1" value="username1" />
    <Attr name="User2" value="username2" />
    <Attr name="User3" value="username3" />
  </UserAttr>
</header>
```

**EDIT** Based on your XSD, it looks like your XML should actually be structured like this:

```
<something>
  <UserAttr Name="User1">
    <Value>username1</Value>
  <UserAttr>
  <UserAttr Name="User2">
    <Value>username2</Value>
  <UserAttr>
  <UserAttr Name="User3">
    <Value>username3</Value>
  <UserAttr>
</something>
```

In that case, the XPath would be something along the lines of

```
/something/UserAttr[@Name = $keyName]/Value
```

We'd need to see more of your XSD in order to know precisely what that `/something` should be.

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe. This worked like a gem:) but as kjhughes replied I noticed that i made a mistake. as per his comment Name is a attribute for UserAttr tag. so now i want to assign attribute to a xsd. i have pasted the XSD format above and now i want to form something like below <UserAttr name="user1"><value/></UserAttr><UserAttr name="user2"><value/></UserAttr>. How to do assign attributes dynamicaly?

Comment: @user3005980 I don't know what you mean by "assign attribute to a xsd". I've added an update above to coincide with your XSD. You should edit your question so that your example XML matches your XSD.